# How to keep bubble (tooltip) up for editing (javascript)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, textbox, tooltip

I have a bubble like div that appears when a div is hovered over. Inside that bubble div, there is a textbox.

How do I make it so that you can hover over the div, the bubble will appear, you can then hover over the bubble, edit inside the textbox, and when the cursor is touching neither the bubble or the textbox, the bubble disappears?

And side not, I don't want it so that you can hover over the bubble and have it appear, only be able to hover over the div first, then the bubble.

Thanks!

Comment: Please show us your code for showing/hiding that bubble.

Answer (score 0):

that is so easy

bubble your bubble ! id
parent your div id

and here we go

```
$('#parent').hover(function(){
   $('#bubble').fadeIn();        
});

$('#bubble').click(function(){
    $(this).fadeOut();        
});
```

---

and one thing more , if you have many bubbles in your page
can you do that , your bubble code be in any div that you want when it hover , this bubble show 
and change your code to under code 
divs that have bubble , have 'tooltip' class , and bubble have class 'bubble'

```
$('.tooltip').hover(function(){
   if($('.bubble',this).hasClass('active')) return false ; // if this bubble is show , do nothing
   $('.bubble.active').fadeOut();// hide any other bubble that is show
   $('.bubble',this).fadeIn().addClass('active'); // show this bubble        
});

$('.bubble').click(function(){
    $(this).fadeOut().removeClass('active');        
});
```

Comment: Doesn't seem to work... I don't think you looked at the question carefully.

Answer (score 0):

Since the question was about javascript not jQuery:

```
    document.getElementById('mydiv').addEventListener('mouseover', function(
        document.getElementById('mybubble').style.visibility='visible';
    ));
    document.getElementById('mybubble').addEventListener('click', function(
        document.getElementById('mybubble').style.visibility='hidden';
    ));
    document.getElementById('mydiv').addEventListener('click', function(
        document.getElementById('mybubble').style.visibility='hidden';
    ));
```

Comment: Doesn't seem to work -- try attaching a jsfiddle to show me in more depth.